# Can we match Any to a generic type? [Scala 2.8]

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

Please point me to correct link if this has been answered before.

I have this code:

```
def getResult(a:Any):Any = a

def getAnswer[T](i:Int) = {
  val result = getResult(i)
  result match {
    case t:T => Some(t)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

This gives me a `unchecked warning` and everything matches to `T`. For instance, when I do `getAnswer[Int](2)`, I get `Some(2)` (as expected). However, if I do `getAnswer[String](2)`, I also get `Some(2)` which is not expected (I need `None`).

Is there any way to work around type erasure and somehow get `getAnswer` to work correctly (i.e., return `Some(result)` if and only if the result is of type `T`)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def getAnswer[T](i:Any)(implicit m:Manifest[T]) = i match {
    case t:Int if m.erasure == classOf[Int] => Some(t)
    case t:Double if m.erasure == classOf[Double] => Some(t)
    //... other Primitives  
    case t if m.erasure.isInstance(t) => Some(t) //this matches AnyRefs
    case _ => None
}
```

As Alexey wrote, you have some trouble with primitives. The technique used in the Scala sources in such cases involves always separate matches for every single primitive type, so I guess there is no way around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer on how to handle primitives. Alexey's answer is also good.

Comment: I selected your answer as correct because it can handle primitive types. Once again, thanks for the code.

Answer (score 5):

This works with some limitations (`T` must be a class and not a primitive type; if `T` is generic, parameters are ignored).

```
def getAnswer[T](i:AnyRef)(implicit m:ClassManifest[T]) = {
  val result = getResult(i)
  if (result.getClass == m.erasure) Some(result.asInstanceOf[T]) else None
}

> getAnswer[java.lang.Integer](2.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
res4: Option[java.lang.Integer] = Some(2)

getAnswer[String](2.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
res1: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: We need to modify `getResult` to also return `AnyRef`. In my case, `T` is always a class or object and never a primitive type, so this may just work for me. I will check and revert.